# KendoGrid with Angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat, kendo-grid

I have kendo-grids in Angular ng-Repeat and serach options on the grids data. 
I want to refresh the grids on search.

This is my code and it doesn't refresh the grids (`$("#kendoGrid1").data("kendoGrid")` is undefined), what Is the fix for this?

**html**

```
<article  ng-repeat="(key,val) in gridsResult" >
    <h2 class="tableTitle">{{key}}</h2>
    <div kendo-grid="kendoGrid{{$index}}" k-options="getGridSlice('{{key}}')"></div>
</article>
```

**js**

```
$scope.getGridSlice = function (index) {
        var data = $scope.gridsResult[index];
        return {
            dataSource: {
                data: data

                }
            },
            columns: [
                        { field: "aa", title: " ", attributes: { "class": "k-header",style:"text-align:center;" }, width:"33px" },
                        { field: "bb", title: "IF", template: rowTemplate.replace(/XX/g, 'IF')}

            ],
            scrollable: false,
            noRecords: true,

        }};
```

scope.onSearch function -

```
 $("#kendoGrid1").data("kendoGrid").datasource.read();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!

The $digest dosen't work on functions so I added k-data-source based on a scope parameter not scope function.
(you need to pull the data from the DB grouped by the grids category)

```
  <article class="tradescreenTable" ng-repeat="(key,val) in gridsResult" ng-class="{'bestAverage': bestAverageSelected}">
                <h2 class="tableTitle">{{key}}</h2>
                <div kendo-grid k-data-source="{{val}}" k-options="gridOptions"></div>
            </article>
```

And k-options

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {

            columns: [
                        { field: "aa", title: " ", attributes: { "class": "k-header",style:"text-align:center;" }, width:"33px" },
                    { field: "bb", title: "IF", template: rowTemplate.replace(/XX/g, 'IF')}
            ],
            scrollable: false,
            noRecords: true,


    };
```

Comment: You need to add also k-rebind="gridsResult" very important!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to refresh the grid:

```
$("#kendoGrid1").data("kendoGrid").datasource.read();
$("#kendoGrid1").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```

Comment: $("#kendoGrid1").data("kendoGrid") is undefined so it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`kendo-grid="kendoGrid{{$index}}"` binds the grid to the `$scope` - you don't need to use jQuery for this (and besides, you're not setting an `id` on the DOM element, so `$("#kendoGrid1")` is never going to work with your code as it is now).

```
$scope.kendoGrid1.datasource.read();
```

The one caveat to this is that I haven't ever tried dynamically setting the name for a Kendo Grid, so I'm not 100% that it works.

Comment: $scope.kendoGrid1 is undefined